# clear a text input if there are non numeric values with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, validation

good morning all, I would like to make a simple widget, that checks a text input on focus and if there are some non numeric characters, it clear the value (ie if there is some kind of text)
actually i' working on this:

```
$("#textinpId").focus(function() {

    if( $(this).val() == "Default Text" ) {
        $(this).val("");
    }

});
```

but i would like to generalize it to not only to "default text" but any non numeric digit (phone numbers), and next but not less important, i would like to trigger the event both on focus and on unfocus, but this part i'm sure i can handle myself :D

is that possible?

Comment: You want to have strictly decimal numbers or it can be a flot number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#textinpId').focus(function(){
    var regex = /^\d+$/;
    if(!regex.test($(this).val())) {
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Following function on onkeypress event for accepting only decimal values

```
<input type="text" onkeypress=" return isNumberKey(event)"/>

  function isNumberKey(evt) {
                var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
                if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31
            && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                    return false;

                return true;
            }
```

For only integer you can use

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')"/>
```

Comment: <input type="text" onkeyup="if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')"/> How to make it into just allowing integer and one decimal with this key up function?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
jQuery('#phone').keyup(function(){
    if(!isNumber($(this).val()))
    {
       $(this).val('');
    }
    });

function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9QFsQ/)**

**UPDATE**

Checking on focus too

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9QFsQ/1/)**

For allowing only `DECIMAL` numbers

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9QFsQ/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using pure javascript and regex

```
var result  = /^[0-9]+$/.test(input);
if(!result)
  $('#textBoxID).val('');
```

This returns true if the input is numeric or false if not.